# Trigger Google Cloud APIs from Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to trigger some Google Cloud APIs from Google Cloud Functions. Could you please help me how I can do this. How to get the Auth TOken and all for this ?

If someone have some example use case that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services#using_services_with_cloud_functions):

> (You can) access Google Cloud Platform APIs from Cloud Function by using a
> service account to act on your behalf. The service account provides
> Application Default Credentials for your functions.
>
> ...
>
> API client libraries that use application default credentials
> automatically obtain the built-in service account credentials from the
> Cloud Functions host at runtime. By default, the client authenticates
> using the `YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account.

So, you don't need to get an Auth Token.

You'll find several examples in the official Firebase Cloud Functions samples page. For example, [this one](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/message-translation/functions/index.js) for the Translate API or [this one](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/moderate-images/functions/index.js) for the Vision API.

There is also a set of examples in the Cloud Functions [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#functions-clone-sample-repository-nodejs) (which covers Cloud Functions written in Python, Go or Java).

Comment: Hi Ranaud,

Actually I want to trigger a Data Fusion Pipeline from Cloud Functions referenced here:https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference

It is a rest api and i am not seeing any Data Fusion thing in google.cloud. How I can achieve this via Cloud Fucntions ?

Comment: Well, this is somehow a different question. The title of your current question is "Trigger Google Cloud APIs from Cloud Functions". I don't know how to trigger a Data Fusion Pipeline from Cloud Functions. You may ask a new question with all these details.

Comment: @SUDHIRGARG you can use directly [the REST API (add an access token to your request header) or the discovery API](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest). If you want more guidance, can you tell my your language, I could share with you code sample.

Comment: Hi Guallaume,

I am coding in python on Cloud fucntions

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something similar to this code.

It was not tested.

For example to call the [Method: projects.locations.instances.get](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.instances/get)

```
def make_func(request):
    
     
    # Get the access token from the metadata server
    metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
    token_response = requests.get(metadata_server_token_url, headers=token_request_headers)
    token_response_decoded = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")
    jwt = json.loads(token_response_decoded)['access_token']
    
    # Use the api you mentioned to create the function
    response = requests.post('https://datafusion.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/your-project/locations/us-central1/instances/your-instance',
                               headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jwt)} )   
    if response:
         return 'Success! Function Created'
    else:
         return str(response.json())
```

Comment: Hi Marian,

Thanks for your answer, I tried using the above. it is generating access_token but when i am running the post request it is giving "Error 401 (Unauthorized)". What is missing here ?

Comment: I think you should deploy your cloud function with a service account that has "roles/datafusion.admin" role.  [Access control](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/access-control). From my understanding you would not need a token to access the api, if you deploy the cloud function with a service account that has the correct role.

Comment: Hi Marian,
I have checked and the role associated with my Function have the 
Cloud Data Fusion Admin attached to it.
I am hitting "https://enterprise-datafusion-downlight-datafusion-xxxx-dot-use1.datafusion.googleusercontent.com/pipelines/ns/dev_rotw/view/Poco-Download-anonymized-hilling-data-if-available" api to trigger a Data fusion Pipeline